# Clickhouse: SummingMergeTree MV to ReplacingMergeTree

Tags: clickhouse

I have a large ReplacingMergeTree table and I know how it deduplicates async. I need a MV which sums up values, but because of it's implemented structure it always sums up duplicated data even using "distinct on" and accurate "order by" since it is applied only on chunk inserted. When I precheck data like "insert where not in select from the same table" performance is dramatically affected with increase in table size.

How can I use SummingMergeTree MV from ReplacingMergeTree? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think it's impossible to do on the Clickhouse's side. Take a look how eBay accomplished deduplication problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4p5mo6IiVHE

Comment: https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf

Comment: @DennyCrane  hello Dennis. Thanks for reply. I have studied this paper throughoutly as well as your video with it and as far as I am concerned SMT MV to ReplacingMT is not the case without pre-deduplication. We should only consider only ReplicaMT for the case, right?

Comment: There is no solution for ReplacingMergeTree & SummingMergeTree. In the future projections will solve this task for ReplacingMergeTree.